# Horizontal scrolling in web view with in the sliding panel layout doesn't work

Tags: android

I am using web view to display the webpage in the sliding panel layout detail view fragment.
after the web page is loaded **horizontal scrolling in the web view** is not possible.

The content moves a bit and the detail page slide to the right to show the master list fragment in the sliding pane layout..

So is there any way to scroll the contents in the webpage.after the full content scrolled  the detail view should be slided in.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by creating custom web view and custom sliding pane layout.you should override onTouchIntercept method of sliding pane layout and the changes has to be done.